# vim - How to escape filename containing single and double quotes mix?

Tags: vim, quoting, filenames

Let's say i create a filename with this:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test$ touch '"i'"'"'m noob.mp4"'
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test$ ls -1
"i'm noob.mp4"
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test$
```

Then `vim .` to go inside Netrw directory listing.

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   /tmp/test
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
"i'm noob.mp4"
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to view the file. Type:

```
:!ls -l %
```

It will shows error:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test$ vim .

ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/i'\''m noob.mp4': No such file or directory

shell returned 2

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I also tried:

[1] `:!ls -l '%'`:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[2] `:!ls -l "%"`:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[3] `:!ls -l expand("%")`:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `ls -l expand(""i'm noob.mp4"")'

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[4] `!ls -l shellescape("%")`:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `ls -l shellescape("/tmp/test/"i'm noob.mp4"")'

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[5] `!ls -l shellescape(expand("%"))`:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `ls -l shellescape(expand("/tmp/test/"i'm noob.mp4""))'

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

My ultimate goal is perform `rsync` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, e.g:

```
nnoremap <C-c> :!eval `ssh-agent -s`; ssh-add; rsync -azvb --no-t % xiaobai@127.0.0.1:/home/xiaobai/storage/
```

My platform is Kali Linux's `vim.gtk3`, bash. Fedora's `vim` and `gvim` also have the same problem.

What's the correct syntax to escape filename containing single and double quotes in vim ?

**[UPDATE]**

`exec '!ls -l' shellescape(expand('%'))` can work, but stil i can't figure out how to make `rsync` above work. I have no idea where should i put quotes for this more complex command `rsync`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `:help filename-modifiers`:

```
The file name modifiers can be used after "%", "#", "#n", "<cfile>", "<sfile>",
"<afile>" or "<abuf>".  ...

...
    :s?pat?sub?
            Substitute the first occurrence of "pat" with "sub".  This
            works like the |:s| command.  "pat" is a regular expression.
            Any character can be used for '?', but it must not occur in
            "pat" or "sub".
            After this, the previous modifiers can be used again.  For
            example ":p", to make a full path after the substitution.
    :gs?pat?sub?
            Substitute all occurrences of "path" with "sub".  Otherwise
            this works like ":s".
```

So rather than just handling double quotes or single quotes, **let's just backslash escape *everything* unusual:**

```
:!ls -l %:gs/[^0-9a-zA-Z_-]/\\&/
```

Works perfectly with the test filename you provided.

To use an absolute path, which you may want for `rsync`, you can add `:p` at the end:

```
:!ls -l %:gs/[^0-9a-zA-Z_-]/\\&/:p
```

---

Actually, it also works just fine if you backslash-escape literally every character, and it's shorter to type:

```
:!ls -l %:gs/./\\&/:p
```

So, in your `rsync` command, **instead of `%`, use `%:gs/./\\&/:p`.**

Answer (score 7):

Building on [Wildcard's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319449/53705) using filename modifiers, `:S` gives you exactly what you want. According to the docs (`:h %:S`),

```
:S      Escape special characters for use with a shell command (see
        |shellescape()|). Must be the last one. Examples:
            :!dir <cfile>:S
            :call system('chmod +w -- ' . expand('%:S'))
```

To use your example:

```
$ touch '"I'\''m also a n00b.txt"'
$ ls
"I'm also a n00b.txt"
```

Then `vim '"I'\''m also a n00b.txt"'`, and voilà:

```
:!ls %:S

"I'm also a n00b.txt"
```

The `:S` filename modifier is [available in Vim 7.4](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v7.4.2367/runtime/doc/cmdline.txt#L908-L911).